# Django / Getting incorrect pk for comment

Tags: python, django

I want to redirect to my post-detail page after entering the comment. In  my code it redirects not to Post's pk, but to Comment's pk. Therefore the path brings me to an incorrect place and the page does not exist.

```
models.py

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments')
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)  


    def __str__(self):
        return self.content

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

```
views.py

class CommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['content']

    def form_valid(self,form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.post = Post.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

```
urls.py

path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name="post-create"),
path('post/<int:pk>/', views.post_detail, name="post-detail"),
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Django Generic views will automatically take the pk of the model the view is assigned, in this case, `Comment`. If you want to change the URL it redirects to you can override `get_success_url` in `CommentCreateView`.

eg,

```
class CommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['content']

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk':self.object.post.pk})
```

Comment: In this case it says, 'method post has no pk member'

Comment: I fixed it with adding object before post since this is is class: def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk':self.object.post.pk})